# updable view can update the base table, but cannot update view column

Tags: postgresql

```
BEGIN;
SET search_path TO test;
CREATE USER regress_view_user1;
CREATE USER regress_view_user2;
GRANT CREATE, usage ON SCHEMA test TO regress_view_user1;
GRANT CREATE, usage ON SCHEMA test TO regress_view_user2;
SET session AUTHORIZATION regress_view_user1;
CREATE TABLE test.base_tbl (
    a int UNIQUE,
    b text,
    c float
);
INSERT INTO test.base_tbl
    VALUES (1, 'xxx', 1.0);
GRANT SELECT (a, b) ON test.base_tbl TO regress_view_user2;
GRANT INSERT (a, b) ON test.base_tbl TO regress_view_user2;
GRANT UPDATE (a, b) ON test.base_tbl TO regress_view_user2;
COMMIT;

SET session AUTHORIZATION regress_view_user2;

CREATE VIEW rw_view2 AS
SELECT
    b AS bb,
    c AS cc,
    a AS aa
FROM
    base_tbl;

INSERT INTO rw_view2 (aa, bb)
    VALUES (1, 'xxx')
ON CONFLICT (aa)
    DO UPDATE SET
        bb = excluded.bb;-- Not allowed
```

`ERROR:  42501: permission denied for table base_tbl`
I am not sure why this would be permission denied.

```
select aa, bb from rw_view2;--permission denied
 select a,b from base_tbl; --permission ok.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: Rewrote this with more detail and a more helpful solution**

Views are implemented in Postgres as [Select rewrite rules](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-views.html) on an empty table which run the `SELECT` statement that you use to define the view. These rewrite rules operate with the same permissions as the owner of the newly created table.

When you execute

```sql
select aa, bb from rw_view2
```

you are likely expecting that the query planner is going to recognize that column cc from rw_view2 isn't needed and therefore a lack of read permissions on column c is irrelevant -and indeed the query planner will actually execute a table scan on base_tbl; however, Postgres going to check permissions BEFORE the query planner does optimization. The rewrite rule is going generate a parse tree equivalent to:

```sql
SELECT aa,bb
FROM (
  SELECT
      b AS bb,
      c AS cc,
      a AS aa
  FROM
      test.base_tbl
) as rw_view2
```

which regress_user2 does not have the permissions to execute, resulting in the error you experience.

Similary

```sql
UPDATE test.rw_view2 SET bb = 'xxx' WHERE aa = 1;
```

fails because what the query planner sees, for purposes of permissions, is something like:

```sql
UPDATE test.base_tbl SET b = 'xxx'
FROM (
 SELECT
     b AS bb,
     c AS cc,
     a AS aa
 FROM
     test.base_tbl
) as rw_view2

WHERE base_tbl.a = rw_view2.aa;
```

You wouldn't want the authorization of operations to succeed or fail based on optimizations the query planner uses -as this would lead to inconsistent behavior that produces difficult-to-debug errors when executing statements.

So fundamentally a user needs `SELECT` permissions on all the columns that they define in their view for any non trivial `INSERT`/`UPDATE` operations.

However, you can work around this restriction by creating the view under regress_user1 and then granting `SELECT`,`UPDATE`,`INSERT` permissions to regress_view_user2. This setup allows you to directly define the permissions you want regress_view_user2 to have on rw_view2 instead of base_tbl:

```sql
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS test;
CREATE SCHEMA test;
CREATE USER regress_view_user1;
CREATE USER regress_view_user2;
GRANT CREATE, usage ON SCHEMA test TO regress_view_user1;
GRANT CREATE, usage ON SCHEMA test TO regress_view_user2;
SET session AUTHORIZATION regress_view_user1;
CREATE TABLE test.base_tbl (
   a int UNIQUE,
   b text,
   c float
);
INSERT INTO test.base_tbl
VALUES (1, 'xxx', 1.0);

CREATE VIEW test.rw_view2 AS
SELECT
    b AS bb,
    c AS cc,
    a AS aa
FROM
    test.base_tbl;

GRANT SELECT (aa,bb) ON test.rw_view2 TO regress_view_user2;
GRANT INSERT (aa,bb) ON test.rw_view2 TO regress_view_user2;
GRANT UPDATE (aa,bb) ON test.rw_view2 TO regress_view_user2;

SET session authorization regress_view_user2;

INSERT INTO test.rw_view2 (aa, bb)
VALUES (1, 'xxx')
ON CONFLICT (aa)
    DO UPDATE SET
    bb = excluded.bb; --succeeds
```

In this case regress_view_user1's `SELECT` permissions on base_tbl allow the view to be computed, and since regress_user2 is only using columns from the view they have been specifically granted access to, the `INSERT ON CONFLICT` operation is allowed to proceed.

If your view has a `WHERE` clause, there are some additional security considerations you might want to take into account when defining views such as using [security_barriers](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/how-do-postgresql-security_barrier-views-work/) and also setting the appropriate `CHECK OPTION` on the view for INSERTS/UPDATES. More info on using rules [here](https://dzone.com/articles/postgresql-rewrite-rules#:%7E:text=When%20you%20define%20a%20rewrite,that%20will%20quickly%20become%20obvious.)